# MYSQL Update across tables not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am attempting to populate all rows in one column of one table with the data from another tables column, with a product code to marry them all up.

So `aatest.stock` to update `products_attributes.attributes_part_number`

This is what I have:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. 
           DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD);

$dbh->exec('UPDATE products_attributes 
        SET aatest.code = products_attributes.attributes_part_number 
        WHERE products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock');

    ?>
```

Any advice as to why this is not working would greatly appreciated.

I'm running MySQL 5.5

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried to debug, have you tried to print your statement before executing to check it's correct.

Comment: I think it should be `UPDATE aatest SET code = products_attributes.attributes_part_number 
        WHERE products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock`

Comment: @Philip Whitehouse: that will throw an error, because that doesn't include a reference to the `products_attributes` table.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your statement "is not working" is because it is invalid MySQL syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Something like this should get you the result you want,
setting the `code` column in the `aatest` table to a value retrieved from the `products_attributes` table column:

```
UPDATE aatest
  JOIN products_attributes 
    ON aatest.stock = products_attributes.attributes_stock
   SET aatest.code = products_attributes.attributes_part_number
```

If you want to avoid the JOIN keyword, you can use the comma operator instead, and move the join predicate from the ON clause to the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE aatest
     , products_attributes 
   SET aatest.code = products_attributes.attributes_part_number
 WHERE aatest.stock = products_attributes.attributes_stock
```

(But that comma-style of join syntax is old school, we favor the `JOIN ... ON` style.)

The way I get to a statement like that is to start with a SELECT statement, like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM aatest
  JOIN products_attributes 
    ON aatest.stock = products_attributes.attributes_stock
```

(If it's a lot of columns, of course, I'll specify the columns of interest.)

The SELECT let's me see what rows are going to be updated, the current value of the `code` column (from aatest), and the new value that will be assigned.

Once I get that working, I can replace the '`SELECT * FROM`' with the '`UPDATE`' keyword, and then add a `SET` clause that specifies the column to be updated.

```
  SET aatest.code = expr
```

(The quirky thing about the update syntax is that the `SET` clause needs to appear before the `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: thanks for such a detailed response. We seem to be getting somewhere now :D problem I'm having now is the entire column is being populated by the data of the first row.

Comment: $dbh->exec('SELECT * FROM aatest JOIN products_attributes ON aatest.stock = products_attributes.attributes_stock');
 $dbh->exec('UPDATE products_attributes JOIN aatest SET products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock');

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a join between the two tables to your UPDATE statement.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE aatest
       JOIN products_attributes on products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock
        SET aatest.code = products_attributes.attributes_part_number
```

Comment: `WHERE products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock` is an implicit inner join

Comment: aatest is the table name with the data, figured that was the link between the two. have I got this wrong?

Comment: You need to have the aatest table in the first part of the statement.  Usually it is the first table in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I swapped the order of the tables since I generally put the table being updated first.

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone for the rapid responses. Tom I've tried that and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE products_attributes, aatest 
    SET aatest.code = products_attributes.attributes_part_number 
        WHERE products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock
```

Comment: I think you need a comma between the 2 table names.  Otherwise MYSQL is going to assume aatest is an alias for the products_attributes table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for all your input, that was really helpful. the correct code in the end was this:

```
$dbh->exec('UPDATE products_attributes, aatest 
            SET products_attributes.attributes_stock = aatest.stock 
            WHERE products_attributes.attributes_part_number = aatest.code');
```

However, the issue I found after pulling my hair out for a few hours was the table I had created in MYSQL had a different encoding (set by default) to the table I was trying to swap data with. Doh!

Hope this helps another budding coder, that is his own worst enemy just like me :D

Thanks again, for all the input. overwhelmed by how quickly you all tried to help.. good first time for me.